# Can I create a link into rundeck that goes straight to the execution of the job?

Tags: rundeck

I have a job without parameters that I would like to give my users to start from a HTML page outside of rundeck.

I'd prefer to not go through additional clicks with the output selection and debug options, but go straight to e.g. https://host/rundeck/project/myproject/execution/show/35#output

But of course the 35 would need to be replaced with $new or something similar, and know that I want to trigger a certain job. Is there a way? Something like https://host/rundeck/project/myproject/execution/show/$new&jobuuid=cce4b26b-8e8a-4920-bd99-4fa3092a3a02 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest approach is to use this ULR `http://localhost:4440/project/ProjectEXAMPLE/job/show/030801bc-6933-472f-ae61-cae11121ca6e` (it needs only a click on the "History" tab).

Comment: Thanks! Yes this is the URL that I'm using to link to the job now, I just hoped to get rid of the last click. No such thing apparently. I image I could trigger the job via the API, and then redirect the user to the jobnumber#output URL, but that doesn't seem worth the trouble.